# Can't boot Linux OSes on new HP laptop

Tags: linux, system-installation

I have got a new HP laptop (ac179tx) which comes with DOS.

I am trying to boot some kind of Linux on it but I am getting problems.

I tried Manjaro KDE but it stucks on "Starting terminate plymouth boot screen". I also tried Kali but it asks for localhost.localdomain login which does not work for username `root` and password `toor`.

However, they seem to work properly on a Desktop. The ISO are good(I have verified checksums) so I have no idea what the problem is. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Tried going lower? SysreCD? Arch? CentOS? Have you tried to find a way to disable the plymouth boot screen altogether for Manjaro? (Kali's error is weird to me)

Comment: @Cestarian I have tried gparted(got kernel panic) and Ubuntu(got blinking cursor), again both worked properly on desktop. I shall try Arch now. how to disable plymouth boot screen?

Comment: @Cestarian BTW is it possible that the laptop is defective? If that must be the case I should have it replaced ASAP. But how would I prove it? Should I try installing some version of windows?

Comment: Yes that would seem to be the case. Try installing some version of Windows (preferably one the laptop officially supports, it seems to support 7 and 10) and if you're still getting errors it must be faulty. If GParted gave you errors you can try the windows disk manager. But by the sound of it, windows might not even make it through the installation (which means that is proof enough)

Comment: @Cestarian Kali Linux did not live boot, but it did get installed when I selected that option instead of live booting. Will try windows but I guess the problem might also be that some part of the hardware(maybe the graphics card) is not suported by Linux yet, as even Kali does not seem to recognise the AMD graphics card.

Comment: No an unsupported GPU would not cause problems this diverse and vague across your installed distros, the problem is elsewhere. (Although I certainly do recall that HP laptops have had a tendency to use their own modified versions of AMD graphics cards that don't exist on any other hardware. Despite this it should be supported as a subset of the graphics card it originally was). How did go installing Windows on it? If windows works fine you can't say the laptop is broken, since it never claimed compatibility with any other OS. If you want to use linux you might want to try to change the laptop.